# How should I set up my connections in a multithreaded app using MvvmCross-SQLite Community Edition?

Tags: multithreading, sqlite, windows-phone-8, mvvmcross

We're experiencing a few problems using the Community.MvvmCross-SQLite project in an mvvmcross app on Windows Phone 8. We have a few background threads (using Task.Run()) that reads/writes to the database in response to updates from a server - since the update might take a few seconds we don't want the UI to freeze up.

When running the app we experience a few crashes where we see messages like "Database missing or corrupt", and when debugging the situation we see a crashes when accessing the database from the background threads.

We've tried to use one common SqliteConnection across the whole project, and everytime we try to write to the database we encapsulate the call in a lock() statement.

- Is it ok to use the same connection, or should we create new ones for every operation?
- What is the state of the multithreaded support in the underlying Community.CSharpLiteSqlite.WP7 library?

Answer (score 0):

SQLite And Multiple Threads

SQLite support three different threading modes:

1.Single-thread. In this mode, all mutexes are disabled and SQLite is unsafe to use in more than a single thread at once.

2.Multi-thread. In this mode, SQLite can be safely used by multiple threads provided that no single database connection is used simultaneously in two or more threads.

3.Serialized. In serialized mode, SQLite can be safely used by multiple threads with no restriction.

[SqliteTheadSafe Documentatioon](https://sqlite.org/threadsafe.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227796/sqlite-database-is-locked-error-in-multithreads-application?rq=1